# asp.net set sessions before postback

Tags: asp.net, session, postback

is there an easy way, to store all needed global variables in sessions at once, before the PostBack starts? Or have I to store them in each step where I change them?
I will do something like:

```
// Global variable.
bool test = true;

// Store all needed information in a session.
protected void Before_globalvariable_is_set_to_default_value(...)
{
    Session["Test"] = test;
    ...
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(IsPostBack)
    {
        //if(Session["Test"] != null)
        //{
            test = (bool)Session["Test"];
            Session.Contents.Remove("Test");
        //}
    }
}
```

Is something like that possible?

**Additional Information**

At the `Page_Load (!IsPostBack)` I check if the user gets more vision, if he gets, I set a global var to true. Later in my code I check if that var is true and add additional columns to a `GridView`.
Now if a `PostBack` occurs, I can’t check that var, because I lose the information. I knew that I need to store the information in a `Session`. If I set the `Session` at the time where I set the global var to true, I get problems with the session timeout (If the user is on the site, but doesn’t do something for a while). So I thought it will be good, if I set the Session shortly before I lose the information of the global var and delete the Session after reinitialization.

That’s my idea, but I don’t know if something like that is possible.

**Edit2:**
If I do following it works:

```
//Global variable
bool test = false;

protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["Test"] = test;
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        test = (bool)Session["Test"]; // Session is true!!!
        Session.Contents.Remove("Test");
    }
    else
    {
        test = true; // Set at the PageLoad the var to true.
    }
}
```

I’m a little bit confused, I thought `PreRender` is after the `PageLoad`, why suddenly the test var is true and if I remove the `PreRender` it isn’t?

Greetz

Comment: Not clear what you want to do, do you want to store some session vars only once, when a new session is started?

Comment: You may check this link http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=126 - try one of the events

Comment: Yes will only store them until the postback is done. After that I will define the global vars with that value from the session. So the session is only a short time alive and I get no problems with expired sessions. See the additional information in my question. I hope it will be clearer. @yytg I will have a look. Thanks.

Comment: @Taz: about your second edit: the first run sets 'test' to true in the Load, then stores that in the Session in PreRender. A postback then reads the Session (in Load) and gets the 'true' value of the previous request.

Comment: @HansKesting Oh I missed that at the first run `PreRender` also run after `PageLoad`. So, it makes sense that the session is true. After the timeout, it will be false again or else the session is expired and deleted. So I just could set the timeout higher, or use a solution with a db or a cookie, like @richaux said.

Comment: @Taz ViewState might also be an option, depending on the exact usage (same page postback).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're worried about losing a specific value between requests, because you've maintained the state of that variable in the `Session` object and it might have been cleared by a timeout, you could consider using another, more durable, mechanism to save the state: for example, cookies or database.

Comment: Mhm I don’t like cookies, they are to unsecure and if I use a db solution, how should I identify the user, with the session id? What should I do if the session id expirer here? Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming you already have a way of identifying the user (e.g. userid or email address ?), so you'd use that, and remove your dependency on Session.

Comment: Oh yea you are right! That comment was rashly… Sorry. Well, that solution takes a little bit more effort, but it’s a nice idea. Do you think that’s the only way I could do it, to prevent from session timeouts? At the moment I reload the page, if a session is expired. It works, but it’s not a nice solution I think… Greetz.

Comment: No problem. :) You could just increase the Session timeout! Otherwise (depending what the site is for) I would say users may expect to reload, or re-authenticate their details, after a period of inactivity. Or, if its an option, use HTTPS if you're concerned about cookie security?

Comment: Sadly I can’t use HTTPS. But see my second editing, if I’m doing it with the `Page_PreRender ` the information’s are back after the `PostBack`, or missed I something?

Answer (score 1):

If the value only needs to live during that one Request, you can use class-level fields of the code-behind class. Set them in the Init or Load phase, then you can use those values in all other phases.

For a lifetime of just a single request:

```
public partial class MyPage: Page
{
   private bool test = true;

   public void Page_Load(...)
   {
      // maybe set 'test' to another value
   }

   public void Button_Click(...)
   {
      // you can still access 'test'
   }

   public void Page_PreRender(...)
   {
      // you can still access 'test'
   }
}
```

If however you need that value to live from request to the **next** postback, you can use `ViewState` instead of `Session`. *Advantage*: no timeout as it is stored in the html and posted back from the browser along with other data. *Disadvantage*: it only works in postback-scanario's, not when you link to a different page.

Comment: Could you explain it a little bit more? Do you mean something like custom properties in a web part? Thanks.

Comment: Okay, please see my second editing. Could you tell me it works with `Page_PreRender`? I don’t know why, or missed i something? Thanks.